# Avoiding mapping property to table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Can anybody tell me about how I can avoid mapping some property from my model to table using code first approach?

Example:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Posted")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modified")]
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

I want UserName do not map into table. It is possible or not in EF?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot about this :(((. I will improve it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a

```
[NotMapped]
```

attribute to the desired property:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Posted")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modified")]
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In code first, override the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext derived class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().Ignore(p => p.UserName);
}
```

Comment: Ok! Can we discuss difference between [NotMapped] attr. and modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().Ignore(p => p.UserName); or it is the same things?

Comment: It is the same thing, but this way you don't need to take a dependency on EntityFramework.dll in the assembly in which your entities are defined. I often like to define my entity classes in their own assembly so they can be tested in isolation.